# Sequences that misses exactly the Polygonal and the $n$-th power numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Can you give an example any such sequence $u_n$ such that it misses exactly the [Polygonal Numbers](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPolygonal_number&ei=cW6RVKHtOYe8uAT8lIGADg&usg=AFQjCNHwmBvrywXzC64FtirjquDBlSMfbA), say for example misses exactly the Pentagonal Numbers and so on? Can you give an example any such sequence $v_n$ which misses exactly the $n$-th powers?

This problem was given to the younger brother of one of my friend and he couldn't solve it. However, after trying for sometime I could show that the sequence $a_n=\left\lfloor n+\dfrac{\sqrt{2n}+1}{2}\right\rfloor$ misses exactly the Triangular Numbers and the sequence $b_n=\left\lfloor n+\dfrac{\sqrt{n}+1}{2}\right\rfloor$ misses exactly the square numbers. So, I think that such two sequences may be possible. However, I am unable to prove the general case.

Can anyone help?

Comment: @pew: Is it ok now?

Comment: By "give an example", do you mean "provide an explicit formula"?

Comment: @pew: Yes. You may take $a_n$ and $b_n$ to be two examples.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** This post answers the question in its original form. The OP has since changed the question and this answer no longer applies. I leave it here for reference anyway.

There is no (infinite) sequence that misses exactly the polygonal numbers.

The $n$th $s$-gonal number is given by

$$P(s,n)=\frac{n^2(s-2)-n(s-4)}{2}$$

Therefore

$$P(s,2)=s$$

In other words, every integer $s>2$ is an $s$-gonal number, and the only integer that is not polygonal at all is $2$ (since $P(s,1)=1$ for every $s$).

Comment: Sorry if my wording wasn't clear. But it is not what I meant. I wanted a sequence which misses say, exactly the Hexagonal Numbers.